# jQuery $(this).attr ('data-id')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have jsp file which display products, product class is entity, and shopping cart is written in js. In jsp I have forEach where I added a button, but it works only with first product others don't work at all.

Is what I wrote wrong? Is the problem on jsp or in js?

jsp page

```
<c:forEach items="${produkt}" var="produkt">
    <div class="produkt-container" style=" border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px;
    width: 300px; margin: 10px ; display: inline-block;text-align:left;">
    <a href="produkt${produkt.id}" >${produkt.model}</a>
    <%--<img src="${produkt.images[o]}" alt="">--%>
    <c:forEach items="${produkt.images}" var="image">
        <img src="${image}" alt="" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 260px">
    </c:forEach>
    <button id="buttonAddToCart"  data-art="${produkt.id}" style="margin: 5px; position: relative"> add to cart </button>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
<script src="js/CartForProdukts.js"></script>
```

js page

```
console.log("test");
var cart = {};
$("#buttonAddToCart").click(function () {
    var produktIdForCart = $(this).attr('data-art');
    if (cart[produktIdForCart] != null) {
        cart[produktIdForCart]++;
    }
    else {
        cart[produktIdForCart] = 1;
    }
    console.log(cart);
});
```

Comment: Your button is outside the for loop so it will not get the id of each product assigned in `data-art`

Comment: it inside, there one more 
</c:forEach></div>

Comment: bad copied , sorry

Comment: If you can create a plinkr or JSfiddle then it will be easy to debug

Comment: $(document).on('click',"#buttonAddToCart",function () {

Comment: If the button is inside the loop, and you're creating multiple buttons, they all end up having the same ID? ID's are unique, jQuery will only get the **first** element with a given ID, as it doesn't expect there to be more

Comment: The reason delegation works for you, is because it just filters on ID, but that still leaves you with the same problem, duplicate ID's and invalid markup.

Comment: Hey even if things work fine after using document, instead of having the id as "buttonAddToCart" keep it as class so the html  will be 
<button class="buttonAddToCart"  data-art="${produkt.id}" >
Also make the changes in js for class selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***An Important Note:-*** `id's` need to be unique per element.So i will ask you to use `class` instead of `id` there like below:-

```
<button class="buttonAddToCart" data-art="${produkt.id}" >
```

And then change jQuery code like below:-

```
$(".buttonAddToCart").on('click',function(){
    var produktIdForCart = $(this).data('art');//prefer to use .data
    //...rest all code as it is
```

Reference:- [When is better to use .data() or .attr()?](https://coderwall.com/p/t_cgwq/when-is-better-to-use-data-or-attr)

***In case If*** these ***buttons*** are ***created dynamically*** then only use jQuery [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(document).on('click',".buttonAddToCart",function(){
    var produktIdForCart = $(this).data('art');//prefer to use .data
    //...rest all code as it is
```

Comment: If the OP used a class, delegating the event all the way up to the `document` level, would be uneccessary

Comment: @adeneo  we don't know what parent element is present already at the time of creating button dynamically. If OP can tell then i can add that parent element id or class. I think whole div is re-created every time.

Comment: The button is created on the serverside, in JSP, at least in the question, so it doesn't need delegation at all, as long as the selector is something other than a bunch of duplicate ID's

Comment: @adeneo  changed my answer accordingly. I hope it will be ok now